# How to specify generic type when the type is only known at runtime?

Tags: java, class, object, templates, generics

I have some code that I need to generate a generic object on the fly with the generic type of 1 of a set of subclasses: e.g. `keyEvent`, `mouseEvent` or `appEvent`, these all extend `event`. So, my generic class `EventFunction` requires a template, however I dont know what the class type is until I recieve the event, so is there a way to do the following:

```
Event event = new KeyEvent(); // FOR EXAMPLE RECIEVING A KEY EVENT
// Require an EventFunction with that event class as the generic type
EventFunction<event.getClass()> func = new EventFunction<event.getClass()>(event);
```

How do I do the above: i.e. specify generic values on the fly?

Comment: But you don't even know the type, how is the language at compile-time supposed to know? Generics is a compile-time mechanism (well, mostly).

Comment: @Shadov: I assume this was _pseudo code_, it shall scribble the _intent_.

Comment: What do you want to do with `func`? You can't know the concrete parameterized type until runtime, so it makes no sense to specify one. The generic super type is `Event`. What would you do with `func` being `EventFunction<Event>`? I think, you'd had to cast _anyway_, if you'd like to have a concrete type when using `func`.

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet may help you:

```
class Event { }

class FooEvent extends Event { }

class EventFunction<T extends Event> {
    public EventFunction(T event) { }
}

class EventFunctionFactory {
   public <T extends Event> EventFunction<T> buildFunction(T event) {
       if (event.getClass().equals(FooEvent.class)) {
            System.out.println("A new FooEventFunction!");          
            return new EventFunction<T>(event);
       }
       else {
           return null;
       }
   }
}
```

Usage is as follows:

```
    EventFunctionFactory factory = new EventFunctionFactory();
    Event foo = new FooEvent();
    EventFunction<Event> function = factory.buildFunction(foo);
```

Here you have a snippet

http://tpcg.io/bMNbkd

Answer (score 0):

Generics only exist for the compiler to check the type safety at compile-time. If your type argument is only known at runtime and not at compile-time, there would be no point to use generics there.