# load class from package name and create object from a template class

Tags: java, templates, generics, classloader

I have a template class like this -

```
public class NodeDAO<T> {
    private static final int DEPTH_LIST = 0;
    private static final int DEPTH_ENTITY = 1;
    final Class<T> typeParameterClass;
    private Session session;

    public NodeDAO(Session session, Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        this.session = session;
        this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
    }

    // other methods and members
}
```

and I have a node class called `Skill` as

```
public class Skill {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String Name;
    private String CleanedText;
    public final static String GraphIdentifier = "skill-ontology";

    @Relationship(type = "BelongsTo", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<SkillSubCluster> belongsTo = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    // other methods.
}
```

I can create a `NodeDAO` object using my `Skill` class like this-

```
NodeDAO<Skill> skillNodeDAO = new NodeDAO<Skill>(session, Skill.class);
```

Every thing looks good, but now I have a requirement where I have been given the path of the file and I have to dynamically create the `NodeDAO` object for it. I tried to follow this tutorial - [Dynamic Class Loading](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/dynamic-class-loading-example/) to load class on runtime. I come up with this code.

```
public void createDAO object(){
    ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    Class<?> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass(fullPath);
    NodeDAO<loadedClass> DAOClass = getGraphNodeDAO(graphIdentifier, loadedClass);
    // Above line or below line throws the same error - cannot be resolved into a type
    //NodeDAO<loadedClass> DAOClass = getGraphNodeDAO(graphIdentifier, loadedClass.getClass());

    // use loadedClass to do other stuffs....
}
```

I am getting the following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    loadedClass cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: Dynamic generic classes is not possible in Java. They are done during the compilation and `NodeDAO<classLoader.loadClass(path)>` does not mean anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54057016/7373144